# Database help Queries

Tags: sql, database-design

How do i do this?

Position 1 = 3 Points.

Position 2 = 2 Points.

Position 3 = 1 Point  in a query design?

Is there a specific formula?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Score = 4 - Position
FROM ...
```

When:

- When Position = 1 you get back 4 - 1, or 3
- When Position = 2 you get back 4 - 2, or 2
- When Position = 3 you get back 4 - 3, or 1

Happy Programming!

Answer (score 1):

CASE WHEN Position = 1 THEN 3 WHEN Position = 2 THEN 2 WHEN Position = 3 THEN 1 End